# how to pass auth token as header from an html file

Tags: javascript, html, fetch, token

i have added an input field which takes token as input and fetches a page with authenctication required and sends that token as header but this doesnt seem to work..all i want to do is take token as input from frontend page and give access to pages instead 0f using POSTMAN

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="token" placeholder="token">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFun()"> submit</button>

  </form>
</body>
<script>
  function myFun() {
    var token = document.getElementById("token");
    object = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token
      }
    }
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/task-list/', object)
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You need a space between `Bearer` and your token (i.e. `'Bearer ' + token`)

Comment: `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token`

Comment: tried it but it didnt help

Comment: Have you checked if you're getting the token (i.e. `console.log(token)`)?

Comment: I checked it in console..it is being received and fetch is sending all the data to that url ..even then its creating a 401/unauthorized error...error is being generated by that url...as if its not permitting a fetch request

Answer (score 0):

```
var token=document.getElementById("token");
```

This selects token id element. You need to fetch the value of the input.

> var token=document.getElementById("token").value;

This will take the value of input box.

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token
```

And Add space after Bearer.

> 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token